# Django - Count related with filter

Tags: python, django

I have a model called `Article` and I have a model called `Comment` which has a foreignkey to `Article`. I want to count from a `Article` queryset all comments in that queryset.

Example: I have a queryset with 5 articles and every article has 3 comments except for one.
-> This should return 12.

Another example: One article has 3 comments and another one has 5 and other articles have no comments.
-> This should return 8.

I tried it with:

```
Article.objects.all().annotate(comments_count=Count("comment", filter=Q(is_deleted=False))).comments_count
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should [**`.aggregate(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate) here, not [<s>**`annotate(..)`**</s> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate). Annotating adds a value to *each* item in the original queryset. We can thus generate a query like:

```
Article.objects.aggregate(
    comments_count=Count('comment', filter=Q(comment__is_deleted=False))
)['comments_count']
```

Although it might be simpler to use the `Comment` model itself here, like:

```
Comment.objects.filter(
    is_deleted=False,
    article__in=my_article_qs
).count()
```

Comment: Ah thank you! I haven't thought of using `article__in`. I will accept your answer in 4 minutes.

Comment: The first solution didn't work for me. I have a field is_deleted on my `Comment` model and Django throws the error: `Cannot resolve keyword 'is_deleted' into field.`.

Comment: @Myzel394: ah but the comment is probably deleted (or not), then the filter is `comment__is_deleted=False`.